# What is conductor to conductor to shield capacitance?

Tags: cables, capacitance, modeling

I am using 6.5 ft (2 meters)  BELDEN 9154 shielded twisted pair cable for a sub 1 MHz application and I wanted to make a model of the cable for some simulations. The [datasheet](https://catalog.belden.com/techdata/EN/9154_techdata.pdf) of the cable lists two capacitance as shown below:
[image]
How to interpret these capacitance? For a 1 ft segment what values of capacitance is observed across the conductors and across shield and one of the conductors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specification you're refering to must be interpreted in the following way:

1. You take one conductor and connect it to shield.
2. Then you take the other conductor and measure the capacitance across it and the other one.

Now take a look at this diagram:

[image: Partial capacitances]

Source of image: [this paper](https://www.ipen.br/biblioteca/cd/ieee/1999/Proceed/00523.pdf). Ignore capacitances \$C_1\$, \$C_2\$, \$C_E\$, and assume that \$C_{S1}=C_{S2}\$.

From the diagram we can see that, because you're shorting one of the conductor to shield, the capacitance measured must be then the parallel of the conductor-to-conductor capacitance \$C_{12}\$ and the conductor-to-shield capacitance \$C_{S1}\$.

Capacitances in parallel add together, so we can calculate the conductor-to-shield capacitance \$C_{S1}\$ from the specification, just subtracting. In this case, the conductor-to shield capacitance \$C_{S1}\$ is just 100 pF/ft - 60 pF/ft = 40 pF/ft. That's a 40 pF/ft from each conductor to shield (two capacitances) in your model. Exactly like **analogsystemsrf** has outlined in his answer.

This is only for the capacitance. If you want a complete lumped model don't forget the rest of parameters (inductance and resistance per length unit) that you can find in the datasheet.

Answer (score 2):

I'd draw the circuit like this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f23jSo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>